# ansible_python_interpreter setting in heterogenous environment

Tags: ansible, debian

I have been working on getting my Ansible molecule testing working on both Debian 8 and Debian 10 docker images. As Debian 10 docker images comes with python 3 by default with no '/usr/bin/python' symlink file. Due to this, molecule testing when run on Debian 10 docker container fails as it cannot /usr/bin/python file. Setting ansible_python_interpreter variable to '/usr/bin/python3' will make molecule test fail on Debian 8 docker containers as it only has python2 installed.

Could someone suggest as possible workaround for this? It would have been good if Ansible itself detects version of python installed on a node but unfortunately thats not the case.

Comment: `It would have been good if Ansible itself detects version of python installed on a node but unfortunately thats not the case` => [are you really sure about that ?](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/reference_appendices/interpreter_discovery.html)

Comment: Just "answering" my rhetoric question: https://gist.github.com/zeitounator/1f1dcfa8623f9923e4f63c1639e65cc0

Comment: And would that not be enough, you can still define `ansible_python_interpreter` in your inventory and adapt the value as you see fit for specific hosts.